# How do I handle validations per-field in a Formik FieldArray?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

### Scenario:

If there are 3 participants, all 3 participants will have the same set of questions but each of those questions have a list of "applied tickets" which will decide whether or not the question gets shown to a specific participant.

### TLDR;

I need to know

1. if it is possible to turn off validations for specific fields at runtime using `yup` (as far as I know this should not be possible since all field validations are provided at the start)
2. what other alternatives do I have to get this validation done ? I'm okay with using Field level validations but I still want to be able to utilize `yup` because of all the in-built validation checks

### Details:

I have a form which requires me to conditionally render specific fields in Formik but also remove the validation from it if the field doesn't exist.

The **specific issue with this form, is that it contains multiple "sub-forms"** handled via Formiks FieldArray. The structure of which looks like this.

[image: Form Structure]

The fields inside these sub-forms can be turned on and off but that doesn't apply for the validation schema.

So far, I've tried using the `yup.when()` function to conditionally render it and it does what's intended but it removes it for all of the elements in the form. The snippet is attached here,

```js
/**
* Given a list of applied tickets, turn off the validation whenever the "id" property
* does not exist in the appliedTickets array
*/
if (field.appliedTickets.length > 0) {
    schema = schema.when("id", {
        is: (value: any) => field.appliedTickets.every((t) => t !== value),
        then: (s) => s.notRequired(),
        otherwise: (s) => s,
    });
}
```

### Update 1 : Added Schema's

#### Main Schema

```js
const personalDetailsSchema = useMemo(() => {
        const ticketSchema = {
            id: string().strip(),
            firstName: string()
                .trim()
                .required(getErrorMessage("firstName.label", { required: true })),
            lastName: string()
                .trim()
                .required(getErrorMessage("lastName.label", { required: true })),
            gender: mixed<Gender>()
                .required(getErrorMessage("gender.label", { required: true }))
                .defined()
                .default(Gender.male),
            email: string()
                .email("Must be a valid email")
                .required(getErrorMessage("email.label", { required: true })),
            dateOfBirth: date()
                .required(getErrorMessage("dateOfBirth.label", { required: true }))
                .typeError("A valid date is required")
                .nullable()
                .default(null),
            nationality: string()
                .oneOf<Country["abbr"]>(
                    allCountries.map((c) => c.abbr),
                    "An available nationality is required"
                )
                .required(getErrorMessage("nationality.label", { required: true }))
                .defined(),
            extraInfo: customQuestionSchema
                ? object({ id: string().strip(), ...customQuestionSchema })
                : mixed().notRequired(),
        };

        const personalDetailsSchema = object({
            tickets: array(object(ticketSchema)),
        });

        return personalDetailsSchema;
    }, [getErrorMessage, customQuestionSchema]);
```

#### Custom Question Schema

Each custom question here has a shape containing isPredefinedType. Based on this, there are two functions that dynamically generate the rest of the schema based on data provided by the custom question.

```js
const customQuestionSchema: Nullable<Record<string, AnySchema>> =
        useMemo(() => {
            if (!customQuestions) {
                return;
            }

            const jointSchema = customQuestions?.reduce((previous, current) => {
                if (current.isPreDefinedType) {
                    const presetQuestionSchema = getPredefinedSchemaFor(current);
                    if (presetQuestionSchema) {
                        return Object.assign(previous, {
                            [presetQuestionSchema.name]: presetQuestionSchema.objectSchema,
                        });
                    }
                }

                const { name, objectSchema } = getCustomSchemaFor(current);
                return Object.assign(previous, {
                    [name]: objectSchema,
                });
            }, {});

            return jointSchema;
        }, [customQuestions, getCustomSchemaFor, getPredefinedSchemaFor]);

const personalDetailsSchema = object({
    tickets: array(object(ticketSchema)),
})
```

Comment: can you create an [example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-mui-v5-forked-ykdjob?file=/src/App.js)?

Comment: @Usama it's a bit difficult given the amount of data I'm working with. But I'd be happy to get on a call or some sort and show you ? There's a lot of complicated logic with some fields so this is the really dumbed down version :/

Comment: can you show the `appliedTickets` array schema, like how the schema looks and where the `id` exists in whole schema etc

Comment: Hi @Usama, I've added the schemas. It still might be difficult to understand given the functions getPredefinedSchema and getCustomSchema are not shown here since its a large amount of code. Feel free to let me know if you need anything more

Comment: there are still confusions in understanding the complete requirement. However, try using `.test` instead of `.when` like `.test('thisIscustomValidation', 'Ticket is required', function (val) { var { parent, from } = this; return true})` . You can `console.log(from)` to check if `id` value exists. The `return true` will make field required and `false` wont. Also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70662719/13405106)

Comment: @Usama so the requirement is that from the admin side of this application. The organiser can toggle certain conditions such as "which participants are these questions applicable for" or "is this question required"

Given the first situation, I have to prevent this question from 

1. Being shown in the Form.
2. Being validated when the form is submitted by formik.

Comment: Yes for toggling on/off validation the `.test` method will work. Try the above mentioned answer and comment. Hope that works

Comment: @Usama would be able to move to a chat ?

Comment: @Usama your method might have worked. But it required me to manually call validations at a field level rather than from the schema level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247846/discussion-between-usama-and-aisirachcha21).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I decided on switching to Field Level Validation whilst still using yup to create a custom and dynamic schema.

I called the `Schema.validate` function manually and assigned the result to the `validate` prop of the Formik `Field` component like below,

```js
const validateField = (name: string, question: CustomQuestion, value: any) => {
    const validationResult = validate(question, value);
    if (validationResult.isError) setFieldError(name, validationResult.message);
        return validationResult.message;
    };
}
```

```js
<FormikDropdown
    {...defaultProps}
    values={question.values}
    onValidate={(value) => validateField(questionFormFieldName, question, value)}
/>
```

To remove the field from the Form completely I had to call the `setValue`, `setError` and `setTouched` in the cleanup function of my `useEffect` hook in the FormikDropdown component that I created like so,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        setValue(undefined);
        setError(undefined);
        setTouched(false);
    };
}, []);
```

This ultimately allowed me to omit specific fields from both being validated and also remove them if they were removed in the middle of the process so that any remaining data wouldn't exist.

I haven't fully tested out any edge cases however and it might still be buggy but as far as my initial testing goes, the approach works as intended

> One small thing to note though. I have omitted the 3 functions from my dependency array. Reason being that for some reason, including them seems to cause an **infinite re-rendering loop**. It's being discussed on [Formik's discussion thread in Github](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/2268) which still doesn't seem to have an official fix at the time of writing.